# JavaScript canvas fillRect visible border

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to render histogram with js canvas, it works fine but I am having some troubles with visible border when using `fillRect`. I know it is caused by bucket width being floating point instead of integer but rouding my bucket width to integer would result in it being too large or too small(depends on buckets amount). So my question is, is there any workaround to get rid of this border?

```js
// problem with bucket width being floating point
const bucketWidth = (Math.round(((desiredHistogramWidth / (data.buckets.length - 1))) * 100) / 100)
for (let i = 0; i < data.buckets.length - 1; ++i) {
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${colors[i][0]}, ${colors[i][1]}, ${colors[i][2]})`;
  const x = histogramXOffset + i * bucketWidth;
  ctx.fillRect(x, histogramHeight, bucketWidth, -data.buckets[i] * heightPixelRatio);
  ctx.fillRect(x, histogramHeight + 20, bucketWidth, 20);
}
```

[image]

This kind of behaviour can be observed in this minimal reproducible example when bucket width is floating point.

```js
const data = [
  1034,
  783,
  700,
  699,
  212,
  123,
  300,
  323,
  344,
  344,
  434,
  344,
  434,
  434,
  0,
  0
];


const canvas = document.getElementById('histogram');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const [ width, height ] = [ canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight ]

ctx.canvas.width = width;
ctx.canvas.height = height;

const max = Math.max(...data);
const heightPixelRatio = ((height) / max);
const bucketWidth = Math.round(width / (data.length) * 100) / 100

console.log(bucketWidth)

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  const x = i * bucketWidth;
  ctx.fillRect(x, height, bucketWidth, -data[i] * heightPixelRatio);
}
```

```css
.histogram {
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #ebecd2;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="histogram" class="histogram"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perhaps just floor the round result? `const bucketWidth = Math.round(width / (data.length) * 100) / 100 | 0`

Comment: That's the issue, I have limited width for this histogram and when computing large amount of buckets the width would eventually become 0 even if I would set minimum width to be 1, histogram can overflow to the right due to the space required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```js
const data = [
  1034,  783,  700,  699,
  212,  123,  300,  323,
  344,  344,  434,  344,
  434,  434,  100,  200
];

const canvas = document.getElementById('histogram');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 180;

const heightRatio = canvas.height / Math.max(...data);
const bucketWidth = canvas.width / data.length

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {  
  ctx.fillRect(
    i * bucketWidth, 
    canvas.height, 
    bucketWidth + 0.5, 
    -data[i] * heightRatio
  );
}
```

```html
<canvas id="histogram" ></canvas>
```

Key points:

- For the bucketWidth we just  use `canvas.width / data.length`
- On the `fillRect` we do `bucketWidth + 0.5` adding a tiny amount

---

Another option I was just experimenting is to just fill once:

```js
const data = [
  1034,  783,  700,  680,
  212,  123,  300,  323,
  354,  340,  434,  344,
  444,  430,  100,  200
];

const canvas = document.getElementById('histogram');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 180;

const heightRatio = canvas.height / Math.max(...data);
const bucketWidth = canvas.width / data.length

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {  
  ctx.rect(
    i * bucketWidth, 
    canvas.height, 
    bucketWidth, 
    -data[i] * heightRatio
  );
}
ctx.fill()
```

```html
<canvas id="histogram" ></canvas>
```

---

For cases with large amount of buckets, you just can not show them all at once, there must be a next button or create some kind of infinite side scroll, there are not many options.
A value of `0.01` can not be a valid `bucketWidth` that just won't display anything